# Interpretation of Regression Coefficients with log transformation

Tags: regression, econometrics, logarithm

I am struggling to understand the interpretation of the regression coefficient in a log-log model, log-linear model and linear-log model. To give an example, let's assume that I have the following model:

$y=\beta _{0}+\beta _{1}x$

And let's assume that

$\hat{\beta _{1}}=5$

This tells us that for a one unite increase in X, there is an average increase of 5 units in Y.

If the model was:

$ln(Y)=\beta _{0}+\beta _{1}ln(X)$

We would say that for an increase of 1% in X, we will have a 5% increase in Y, on average.

If the model was:

$ln(Y)=\beta _{0}+\beta _{1}X$

We would say that for a 1 unit increase in X, Y will increase on average by 500%.

And if our model was:

$Y=\beta _{0}+\beta _{1}ln(X)$

We would say that for a 1% increase of X, Y will increase by 0.05 units on average.

I understand the basic interpretation, but don't understand where the other interpretations comes from. Can you please clear this up a bit ? Thank you !

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=log+regression+interpret*

Comment: I have closed this as "too broad" because I believe every one of these individual questions is answered, extensively and in detail, in existing threads, but not in any single thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the impact as a difference $after - before$ : For each increase of  $\Delta X$ there is a $\Delta Y$ impact.

- For the linear model :

$$Y_1 - Y_0 = \beta _0 - \beta_0 + \beta_1*(X_1-X_0 ) $$
Hence $\Delta Y  = \beta_1 * \Delta X$

For the log - log model the percentage increase you describe are true for small increases of X: $ln(1+x) \sim x$

- For the Log-Log model:
  $$ln(Y_1) - ln(Y_0) = \beta _0 - \beta_0 + \beta_1*(ln(X_1)-ln(X_0) ) $$
  $$ln \left( \frac{Y_1}{Y_0} \right)  = \beta_1* \left( ln \left( \frac{X_1}{X_0} \right)\right)$$

So for a percentage increase of 1% of $x$ we rely on the above approximation to say that:
$$ ln \left( \frac{Y_1}{Y_0} \right) = \beta_1 * ln \left( \frac{X_0 + 0.01X_0}{X_0} \right) \sim \beta_1*0.01$$ 
$$\Rightarrow Y_1 = Y_0 * e^{0.05} \sim 1.05 * Y_0$$

- For the Log-Lin model

$ln(Y_1) - ln(Y_0) = +\beta _{1} * (X_1 - X_0) $

If $X$ increases by 1 unit :

$ ln(Y_1) - ln(Y_0) = \beta_1 *((X_0 + 1) - X_0) $

$ ln \left( \frac{Y_1}{Y_0} \right) = 5 $

After applying the exponential function and rearranging:
$ Y_1 = e^5 * Y_0 $

$ Y_1 = 148.41 * Y_0 = Y_0 * (100 + 14741.31) \%  $

For such large increases we can see that the approximation for small values can not be used anymore.

- For the Lin - Log model 
  We re-use the approximation again, and as you pointed out an increase of 1% of $X$ has more or less a 5% impact on $Y$:

$\Delta Y =  \beta_1 ln \left ( \frac{ 1.01 X_0}{X_0}\right)$

$\Delta Y \sim 5 * 0.01 = 5\%$